# Kerberos SSO integration

Tags: java, active-directory, kerberos, apache-tomee, spnego

I'm trying to implement Kerberos SSO authentication for a web based application, but haven't had much luck researching how to accomplish this. I was assigned this project late in an internship and probably won't finish, but I want to make as much progress as I can. I'd like to authenticate a Windows client to a TomEE server against Active Directory. I've found a lot of resources describing the protocol in high-level terms, but don't know where to begin in terms of code.

For example, how would I validate and send tickets to other principals? What does Kerberos handle and what do I need to implement from the ground up?

Also, how do things like SSPI, SPNEGO, etc. fit into the picture?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://tomcatspnegoad.sourceforge.net/) is all you need for Tomcat. It needs slight modifications for Tomcat 8.x because the API has changed but the rest remains as-is.